# Text as parameter in inline assembly (ARM)?

Tags: gcc, arm, inline-assembly

Is there a way to put plain text in inline assembly (ARM)?
My problem is reading banked registers.
The syntax is (r11 of user mode):

```
mrs r0, r11_usr
```

The problem is the "usr"-part.

I tried:

```
#define READ_REG_MODE(retvar, rg, mode) \
    asm volatile (\
    "mrs %[reg], r%c[rn]_%c[mod]\n\t"\
    :[reg] "=r" (retvar)\
    :[rn]"I"(rg), [mod]"X"("mode"):\
    )
```

with and without quotations both in this macro and in the macro-call.
With [mod]"X"("mode") I got:

> Error: selected processor does not support requested special purpose
>   register -- `mrs r0,r11_.LC0'

Comment: If this is a preprocessor macro, then there's no need to even consider assembly specifically - the C preprocessor is perfectly capable of tokenising macro arguments and concatenating strings, regardless of what they represent ;)

Comment: The problem is that the replacement should be done within quotation. That the macro-replacement doesn't do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't actually need to get anywhere near the assembler - it's something the C preprocessor can handle all by itself using the "stringification" [# operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/preprocessor/replace):

```
#define READ_REG_MODE(retvar, rg, mode) \
    asm volatile (\
    "mrs %[reg], r%c[rn]_" #mode "\n\t"\
    :[reg] "=r" (retvar)\
    :[rn]"I"(rg):\
    )
```